# Controlling the spawn of objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game where I have to spawn balls going down, but I want to control if there's another ball under it and depending the kind of ball, another ball is created in another position or not. Sorry if you don´t understand Spanish but the comments are in Spanish. Things you maybe need to know: probability is a function that returns an int between the number of possibilities that you have given in this case 3, killerAst is a prefab with a collider2D. There is another same function in the script but it doesn't generate "choos" randomly, you have to give it.

Here is the code I try.

```
public void SpawnAst()
    {
        //Escogemos que asteroide vamos a crear
        int choos = Probability(34, 33, 33);

        //Instanciamos el asteroide
        GameObject spwn = Instantiate(ast[choos],
                    new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.8f, 2.8f), 5.50f, 0f),
                    Quaternion.identity, canvas.transform);

        //Creamos un objeto llamado hit que servira como el campo en el que comprobaremos si hay algun asteroide
        GameObject hit = Instantiate(killerAst, spwn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        //metemos en un array todos los gameObject del juego
        GameObject[] g = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        //Hacemos un bucle for por todos los gameobjects del juegp
        foreach (GameObject game in g)
        {
            //Si el gameobject contiene el tag Asteroid
            if (game.tag == "Asteroid"  && game != spwn)
            {
                //Y esta dentro de la caja de colisiones
                if (hit.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.Contains(game.transform.position))
                {
                    //Ejectuamos que vamos a hacer dependiendo el asteroide que hemos creado
                    switch (choos)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (game.GetComponent<FreezeAstContrll>() != null)
                            {
                                Destroy(spwn);
                                SpawnAst(choos);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Destroy(spwn);
                            SpawnAst(choos);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (game.GetComponent<FreezeAstContrll>() != null)
                            {
                                Destroy(spwn);
                                SpawnAst(choos);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Destroy(hit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code? What's it doing now and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I try to detect what balls are below and if the ball is a specific one, a new ball is created, but for some reason the code does not work

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean? Does it not compile? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: there is no problem with compling or giving any exception, it is simply that the balls do not change their position when they should

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Comment: You should get an exception latest the second time when `hit.GetComponent<Collider2D>()` is reached since you already `Destroy(hit)` after the first iteration of your `foreach` loop ... also why spawning and deleting an object all the time just to see if something is within its collider? Rather simply keep one and set it (in)active instead.